# React/redux TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've got a react application using react-redux 7.2.
Whenever I modify the state and try to persist it I get the following error (See stack trace below)

> TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
> --> starting at object with constructor 'Object'
> --- property 'id' closes the circle
> at JSON.stringify ()
> at persistState (Storage.js:54)
> at store.js:30
> at dispatch (redux.js:222)
> at redux-saga-core.esm.js:1410
> at middleware.js:22
> at Object.setConfirmDeliveryVisible (redux.js:477)
> at CreateEditOrderContainer.handleSaveOrder (CreateEditOrderContainer.js:171)
> at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
> at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
> at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
> at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:306)
> at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:389)
> at executeDispatchesInOrder (react-dom.development.js:414)
> at executeDispatchesAndRelease (react-dom.development.js:3278)
> at executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3287)
> at forEachAccumulated (react-dom.development.js:3259)
> at runEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3304)
> at runExtractedPluginEventsInBatch (react-dom.development.js:3514)
> at handleTopLevel (react-dom.development.js:3558)
> at batchedEventUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21871)
> at batchedEventUpdates (react-dom.development.js:795)
> at dispatchEventForLegacyPluginEventSystem (react-dom.development.js:3568)
> at attemptToDispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4267)
> at dispatchEvent (react-dom.development.js:4189)
> at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
> at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
> at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:21887)
> at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:806)
> at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:4168)

I've not found a clue as of why a circular reference is being created. I've made sure that the action is being called just once and seems to be alright. Also, uninstalled the redux-dev chrome extension. So far no luck.

Any insights into this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No one could help you if you don't provide some piece of code or data relevant. Pls

Comment: Most likely you have a circular structure in the state itself.  A circular structure occurs when a node in an object tree is a reference to another node higher in the tree.